# Downloading Blob from Docusign Envelopes API

Tags: meteor, docusignapi

Using Meteor HTTP I'm able to get a response from docusign and convert to a base64 buffer.

```
try {
   const response = HTTP.get(`${baseUrl}/envelopes/${envelopeId}/documents/1`, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
   const buffer = new Buffer(response.content).toString('base64');
   return buffer
  } catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
   throw new Meteor.Error(e.reason);
}
```

Then on the client I'm using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to `saveAs` a blob created from an ArrayBuffer via this function

```
function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
const binary_string =  window.atob(base64);
const len = binary_string.length;
const bytes = new Uint8Array( len );
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++)        {
    bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
}
return bytes.buffer;
}


// template helper

'click [data-action="download"]'(e, tmpl){
  const doc = this;
  return Meteor.call('downloadPDF', doc, (err, pdf)=>{
    if(err) {
      return notify({
        message: err,
        timeout: 3000,
      })
   }
  const pdfBuffer =  pdf && _base64ToArrayBuffer(pdf);
  console.log(pdfBuffer);
  return  saveAs(new Blob([pdfBuffer], {type: 'application/pdf'}), `docusign_pdf.pdf`);
});
},
```

The PDF is downloading with the correct size and page length, but all the pages are blank. Should I be encoding the buffer differently? Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

When uploading documents into DocuSign you can either send the raw document bytes as part of a `multipart/form-data request` or you can send the document as a `base64` encoded file in the `document` node in your request body.

However once the envelope is complete the DocuSign platform converts the doc into a PDF (if it wasn't one already) and provides that raw file.  As such, you shouldn't have to base64 decode the doc so I would try removing that part of your code.

Comment: Ok, interesting, thank you. However, iff I just return the `result.content` from the api and create a blob directly from that, It still downloads the correct size PDF and correct number of pages, but all the pages are blank.

edit: for what it's worth, I can hit the API with Postman and it downloads the file just fine.

Comment: @xhaque --  Since it's working with Postman, it sounds like an issue with your Meteor setup....

Comment: @xhaque: When you are encoding to base64, try to decode same in next line and see if you are seeing the same content or not. It seems encoding/decoding to/from base64 is corrupting the pdf. Do decode after `const buffer = new Buffer(response.content).toString('base64');`